# How to generate animation from manipulate?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, animation

I  simulated a spherical shaped robot `(Snippet-a)`. I used `Snippet-b` to generate the Graphics using manipulate.

1. How to save this as an animation to a video file?
2. `PlotRange` command is not working in `Snipped-b`. No matter the changes I made it still plots x-axis and y-axis between -10 to 10. Is this a bug?

> snippet-a

```
r = 1; kp = 100; kv = 10; \[Theta] = 0; xdes = 2; ydes = 1; pos = {1, 
  1, 1}; los = pos/Norm[pos];
Rdes = RotationMatrix[\[Theta], los];
Pdes = {xdes, ydes, 0};
R = {{r11[t], r12[t], r13[t]}, {r21[t], r22[t], r23[t]}, {r31[t], 
   r32[t], r33[t]}}; r11d = D[r11[t], t]; 
r12d = D[r12[t], t]; 
r13d = D[r13[t], t]; 
r21d = D[r21[t], t]; 
r22d = D[r22[t], t]; 
r23d = D[r23[t], t]; 
r31d = D[r31[t], t]; 
r32d = D[r32[t], t]; 
r33d = D[r33[t], t]; 
xd = D[x[t], t];
yd = D[y[t], t];
w = {w1[t], w2[t], w3[t]};
what = {{0, -w3 [t], w2[t]}, {w3[t], 0, -w1[t]}, {-w2[t], w1[t], 0}};
w1d = D[w1[t], t]; w2d = D[w2[t], t]; w3d = D[w3[t], t];
e1 = {1, 0, 0}; e2 = {0, 1, 0}; e3 = {0, 0, 1};
J = DiagonalMatrix[{.3, .4, .5}];
(*Fff=Cross[Transpose[R].e3,w]+0.5 \
(Cross[w,Transpose[R].e3]+Inverse[J].(Cross[w,J.Transpose[R].e3]-\
Cross[J.w,Transpose[R].e3]));*)
wdes = r*(R\[Transpose].e3) - los;(*Omega desired*)
P = {x[t], y[t], r};
Pbar = R\[Transpose].(P - Pdes) - r*los;
dpsi = wdes\[Cross]Pbar;
ew = w - wdes;
Fpd = -Inverse[J].(kp*dpsi + kv*ew);
Fff = (R\[Transpose].e3)\[Cross]w*r + wdes\[Cross]w + 
   1/2*(w\[Cross]wdes + 
      Inverse[J].(w\[Cross](J.wdes) - (J.w)\[Cross]wdes));
(*Fff=(R\[Transpose].e3)\[Cross]w+1/2 \
(w\[Cross](R\[Transpose].e3)+Inverse[J].(w\[Cross](J.R\[Transpose].e3)\
-(J.w)\[Cross](R\[Transpose].e3)));
Fpd=-Inverse[J].(kp r R\[Transpose].(x[t]*e2-y[t]*e1)+kv*(w-R\
\[Transpose].e3));*)
F = -Inverse[J].(w\[Cross](J.w)) + Fff + Fpd;
Rd = R.what;
dae2 = {r11d == Rd[[1, 1]], 
   r12d == Rd[[1, 2]], 
   r13d == Rd[[1, 3]], 
   r21d == Rd[[2, 1]], 
   r22d == Rd[[2, 2]], 
   r23d == Rd[[2, 3]], 
   r31d == Rd[[3, 1]], 
   r32d == Rd[[3, 2]], 
   r33d == Rd[[3, 3]], 
   xd == r*(r21[t]*w1[t] + r22[t]*w2[t] + r23[t]*w3[t]),
   yd == -r*(r11[t]*w1[t] + r12[t]*w2[t] + r13[t]*w3[t]),
   w1d == F[[1]], w2d == F[[2]], w3d == F[[3]],
   w1[0] == 0, w2[0] == 0, w3[0] == 0,
   r11[0] == 1, r12[0] == 0, r13[0] == 0,
   r21[0] == 0, r22[0] == (0.5)^0.5, r23[0] == -(0.5)^0.5,
   r31[0] == 0, r32[0] == (0.5)^0.5, r33[0] == (0.5)^0.5,
   x[0] == 9, y[0] == 9};
simtime = 4
sol = NDSolve[
  dae2, {r11, r12, r13, r21, r22, r23, r31, r32, r33, x, y, w1, w2, 
   w3}, {t, 0, simtime}, MaxSteps -> 10000000]; 
plotb = ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
    Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], 0}, {t, 0, simtime}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {0, 3*r}},
   AxesLabel -> {Style[x, FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 48], 
     Style[y, FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 48]},
   ImageSize -> 700, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 24}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Hue[0.7]}];
```

> snipped-b

```
Manipulate[Show[plotb, Graphics3D[
   {Sphere[{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
      Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r}, r],
    Thickness[0.01], Red, 
    Line[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol],
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r}
       + 2*
        r*{Evaluate[r11[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r21[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r31[t]] /. First[sol]}}],
    Thickness[0.01], Green, 
    Line[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol],
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r}
       + 2*
        r*{Evaluate[r12[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r22[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r32[t]] /. First[sol]}}],
    Thickness[0.01], Blue, 
    Line[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol],
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r}
       + 2*
        r*{Evaluate[r13[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r23[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r33[t]] /. First[sol]}}],
    Thick, Black, Line[{{0, -3, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}],
    Thick, Black, Line[{{-5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}],
    Thick, Blue, Line[{{xdes, ydes, r + 3}, {xdes, ydes, 0}}],
    Thick, Red, Line[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes + 5, ydes, r}}],
    Thick, Green, Line[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes + 5, r}}],
    Thick, 
    Red, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes, r} + 
        2.5*Evaluate[ Rdes.e1 /. First[sol]]}]},
    Thick, 
    Green, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes, r} + 
        2.5*Evaluate[ Rdes.e2 /. First[sol]]}]},
    Thick, 
    Blue, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes, r} + 
        2.5*Evaluate[ Rdes.e3 /. First[sol]]}]},
    Thick, 
    Black, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], 
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[y[t] /. First[sol]], r} + 
        1.2*Evaluate[ {{r11[t], r12[t], r13[t]}, {r21[t], r22[t], 
              r23[t]}, {r31[t], r32[t], r33[t]}}.pos /. 
           First[sol]]}]}}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 18}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 7}, {-1, 7}, {0, 10*r}}, ImageSize -> 900]], {t,
   0, simtime}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1: "How to save this as an animation to a video file?"**

This one is pretty easy. Simply `Export` your `Manipulate` to a gif or AVI or similar.

```
Export["question.gif", %, AnimationRepetitions->Infinity]
```

[image]

Instead of `%` here, you could place your entire `Manipulate`.

(You can also do `"question.avi"` and so on. The `AnimationRepetitions` is simply so the gif repeats more than once.)

---

**Question 2: PlotRange command is not working in Snipped-b. No matter the changes I made it still plots x-axis and y-axis between -10 to 10. Is this a bug?**

You have wrapped your `Graphics3D` in a `Show`, to show both the ball and your plots. However, you have not given the `PlotRange` to the `Show` - only to the `Graphics3D`. The `Show` then overrides this. You can solve this by passing the display options to the `Show` instead:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[plotb, 
  Graphics3D[{Sphere[{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
      Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r}, r], Thickness[0.01], Red, 
    Line[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol],
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r} + 
       2*r*{Evaluate[r11[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r21[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r31[t]] /. First[sol]}}], Thickness[0.01], Green, 
    Line[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol],
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r} + 
       2*r*{Evaluate[r12[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r22[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r32[t]] /. First[sol]}}], Thickness[0.01], Blue, 
    Line[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol],
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], r} + 
       2*r*{Evaluate[r13[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r23[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[r33[t]] /. First[sol]}}], Thick, Black, 
    Line[{{0, -3, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}], Thick, Black, 
    Line[{{-5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}], Thick, Blue, 
    Line[{{xdes, ydes, r + 3}, {xdes, ydes, 0}}], Thick, Red, 
    Line[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes + 5, ydes, r}}], Thick, Green, 
    Line[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes + 5, r}}], Thick, 
    Red, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes, r} + 
        2.5*Evaluate[Rdes.e1 /. First[sol]]}]}, Thick, 
    Green, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes, r} + 
        2.5*Evaluate[Rdes.e2 /. First[sol]]}]}, Thick, 
    Blue, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{xdes, ydes, r}, {xdes, ydes, r} + 
        2.5*Evaluate[Rdes.e3 /. First[sol]]}]}, Thick, 
    Black, {Arrowheads[.03], 
     Arrow[{{Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
        Evaluate[y[t]] /. First[sol], 
        r}, {Evaluate[x[t]] /. First[sol], 
         Evaluate[y[t] /. First[sol]], r} + 
        1.2*Evaluate[{{r11[t], r12[t], r13[t]}, {r21[t], r22[t], 
              r23[t]}, {r31[t], r32[t], r33[t]}}.pos /. 
           First[sol]]}]}}], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 18}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 7}, {-1, 7}, {0, 10*r}}, ImageSize -> 900], {t, 
  0, simtime}]
```